# Is it okay to use the barplot function without specifying `order?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on the Titanic dataset based on this Kaggle [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/startupsci/titanic-data-science-solutions/notebook). On the part where I'm trying to use the barplot function, it gives me a warning message `UserWarning: Using the barplot function without specifying order` is likely to produce an incorrect plot.

Should I be concerned?

I've tried to specify the order parameter and the hue_order as well.

```py
grid = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, col='Embarked', row='Survived', height=2.2, aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.barplot, 'Sex', 'Fare', alpha=0.5, ci=None, order=[1,2,3], hue_order=['Embarked', 'Survived'])
grid.add_legend()
```

When I specified the order and hue_order it gave me empty bar plots.
[empty barplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTwkA.jpg)

However, when I take out the order and hue_order, it does give me the plots with this warning message:

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py:715: UserWarning: Using the barplot function without specifying `order` is likely to produce an incorrect plot.
warnings.warn(warning)
```

[results with error warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdn1t.jpg)

Any thoughts or tips that I should know? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot catch anything that seems wrong in your code. Have you tried `plt.show()` command already? Sometimes it may affect the outcome ....

Comment: @cyber-math I did and it gives me the results but still with the same warning message.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how to fix the warning with the sns.Facetgrid. You can use catplot instead to draw the exact same plot.

Here is my code:

```
g = sns.catplot(x="Sex", y='Fare', row="Embarked",
                   col='Survived', data=train_df,kind ='bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

The ordering in your code should be based on `Sex` category. So, if I were to rewrite your code, it would be something like this:

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, col='Embarked', row='Survived', height=2.2, aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.barplot, 'Sex', 'Fare', alpha=0.5, ci=None, order=['female', 'male'])
grid.add_legend()
```

I did check this code and it does not raise any warning.